# Does the D365 SDK exist for Mac?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to Microsoft Dynamics development so apologies if this question is basic.

I'm looking to publish a plugin to a Dynamics E3 instance for testing/development, and it seems like I need to use the Plugin Registration Tool to do this. I've found https://xrm.tools/SDK, but it seems like there's no option to run these on a Mac (my development environment).

Is my best option here to use a Windows machine, or is there an SDK for Unix-based systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is currently Windows only, on the full .NET Framework. 
Microsoft has said they'll be delivering a .NET Core-compatible version of the SDK at some point, which should open up SDK development on other platforms.

Beyond that, the release of .NET 5 (slated for November 2020) will unify the .NET Framework into single version across all platforms.

Until the .NET Core version comes out, you can use the [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-api) to develop apps on other platforms.